# jQuery UI 4 buttons. Code repeated 4 times, Can we make it shorter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button

```
$('#elmLeft').button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-w"
            },
            text: false
        });
$('#elmRight').button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"
            },
            text: false
        });
$('#elmTop').button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-n"
            },
            text: false
        });
$('#elmBottom').button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function setButton($element, icon) {
    $element.button({
            icons: {
                primary: icon
            },
            text: false
        });
}
setButton($('#elmLeft'), "ui-icon-triangle-1-w");
setButton($('#elmRight'), "ui-icon-triangle-1-e");
setButton($('#elmTop'), "ui-icon-triangle-1-n");
setButton($('#elmBottom'), "ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
```

Alternatively you could just take the selector instead of a jQuery element, and only the last letter of the string, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the icon differences in an object and use that to alter `primary`:

```
var icons = {
    elmLeft:   'w',
    elmRight:  'e',
    elmTop:    'n',
    elmBottom: 's'
};
$('#elmLeft, #elmRight, #elmTop, #elmBottom').each(function() {
    $(this).button({
        icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-' + icons[this.id] },
        text:  false
    });
});
```

I don't know if you'd consider that DRY enough to warrant the extra complexity though. If you had a class on the buttons then you could make it cleaner with:

```
$('.some_class').each(function() {
    // As above.
});
```

Or perhaps you could add a function to `icons` to keep the `id` and icon information together:

```
var icons = {
    elmLeft:   'w',
    elmRight:  'e',
    elmTop:    'n',
    elmBottom: 's',
    button: function(id) {
        $('#' + id').button({
            icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-' + this[id] },
            text:  false
        });
    }
};
icons.button('elmLeft');
icons.button('elmRight');
icons.button('elmTop');
icons.button('elmBottom');
```

Or take it one step further:

```
var buttons = {
    ids: {
        elmLeft:   'w',
        elmRight:  'e',
        elmTop:    'n',
        elmBottom: 's'
    },
    create: function() {
        for(id in this.ids) {
            if(this.ids.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                $('#' + id').button({
                    icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-' + this.ids[id] },
                    text:  false
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
buttons.create();
```

You could do the above with a self-executing function if you wanted a cleaner namespace:

```
(function() {
    var ids = {
        elmLeft:   'w',
        elmRight:  'e',
        elmTop:    'n',
        elmBottom: 's'
    };
    for(id in ids) {
        if(ids.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            $('#' + id').button({
                icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-' + ids[id] },
                text:  false
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks +1. But I think Davy's answer is more practical.

Comment: +1/-1  for over-engineering (so net of 0, cool, but leaves the reader of the code thinking wtf is this supposed to do?)

Comment: @Davy8: In practice I would have used Pinkie's original and reformatted it to make finding the difference easier (and probably added a comment to point out where the difference was). But sometimes I feel playful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it could be made shorter, but not in an elegant way as far as i can see, and the brevity would come at a cost of understandability.